# Problem when try to install Selenium on python3

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Im trying to install selenium on python 3.6.

With command

> pip install selenium

i got this error :

> Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/80/d6/4294f0b4bce4de0abf13e17190289f9d0613b0a44e5dd6a7f5ca98459853/selenium-3.141.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from selenium) (1.22)
>   Installing collected packages: selenium
>   Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium-3.141.0.dist-info'
>   Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

I saw people getting similar mistakes, but the solutions did not help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `--user` at last of your install command, so that the package will be installed only for the current user, not for all.

```
sudo pip install xxxxxx --user
```

If that solution did not change your issue please type following code to terminal and try to run `pip install selenium` after that.It is directly related with read/write access to that directory.

sudo chown -R username /usr/local/lib/python3.6/

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
> sudo pip install -U selenium
```